# Rewriting Certain parts of a text file (dynamically)

Tags: python, file, url-rewriting

I have a text file like this

```
A,OXXX#XXXX#XXOO
B,OOXX#XXXX#XXOO
C,OXXX#XXXO#OXXO
D,OOXX#XXXX#XXOO
E,OOOX#OXXO#XXOO
F,##XX#OXXX#XO##
```

Its something like a movie cinema
Where O is available seats, X is unavailable seats and # is a wall

```
bookSeat = input('Enter seats to book: ').split(',')
    for booking in bookSeat:
        bookRow = booking[0]
        bookColumn = booking[1:]
        availableSeats = seatingPlan[bookRow][int(bookColumn)-1]
            if availableSeats == 'O':
                f = open('Monkey Goes East-202209081430.txt','w')
                #idk whats the next step
            elif availableSeats == 'X':
                print("Seats are already booked!')
            elif availableSeats == '#':
                print('These seats are unavailable')
```

So if i input A1,B14, it will update the text file into

```
A,**X**XXX#XXXX#XXOO
B,OOXX#XXXX#XXO**X**
C,OXXX#XXXO#OXXO
D,OOXX#XXXX#XXOO
E,OOOX#OXXO#XXOO
F,##XX#OXXX#XO##
```

Bolded to show its been change

please help

Comment: *Please help*... with what? There is no question here, just some code.

Comment: i guess `#idk whats the next step` is the question. you could read the lines of the file into a list before you loop. then modify the list accordingly and write the list back to the file after you're finished looping.

Comment: modifying and then writing it back is the part i'm trying to do but i dont know how

Comment: what is `seatingPlan`? a dictionary with letters as keys and lists of strings as items? can you modify the `seatingPlan` variable directly? so instead of `f = open('Monkey Goes East-202209081430.txt','w')` can you write `seatingPlan[bookRow][int(bookColumn)-1] = 'X'`?

Answer (score 0):

assuming `seatingPlan` is a python dict like `{'A': ['X','#','O', ...]}` and assuming you can modify `seatingPlan` you could do something along the lines of:

this is pseudo-code. i did not test it.

```py
bookSeat = input('Enter seats to book: ').split(',')
isFullyBookable = True

for booking in bookSeat:
    bookRow = booking[0]
    bookColumn = booking[1:]
    availableSeats = seatingPlan[bookRow][int(bookColumn)-1]
    
    if availableSeats == 'O':
        seatingPlan[bookRow][int(bookColumn)-1] = 'X'
    elif availableSeats == 'X':
        print('Seats are already booked!')
        isFullyBookable = False
    elif availableSeats == '#':
        print('These seats are unavailable')
        isFullyBookable = False
    # further checking logic ....

if isFullyBookable:
    with open('Monkey Goes East-202209081430.txt','w') as f:
        for rowCode in sorted(seatingPlan.keys()):
            f.write(rowCode + ',' + "".join(seatingPlan[rowCode]) + '\n')
```

Comment: That is what i was looking for! haha thanks! sorry im not able to phrase my questions correctly because im very new to this... 

btw what does the 
f.write(rowCode + ',' + "".join(seatingPlan[rowCode]))
do?
what if i dont want to change the look of the file and want it to stay
A,OXXX#XXXX#XXOO\n
B,OOXX#XXXX#XXOO\n
C,OXXX#XXXO#OXXO\n
D,OOXX#XXXX#XXOO\n
E,OOOX#OXXO#XXOO\n
F,##XX#OXXX#XO##\n
(cant format it in comments so...)
because right not after rewriting, the file becomes 1 line like
A,OXXX#XXXX#XXOOB,OOXX#XXXX#XXOOC,OXXX#XXXO#OXXOD,OOXX#XXXX#XXOE,OOOX#OXXO#XXOOF,##XX#OXXX#XO##

Comment: `"".join(list)` turns a list of strings into a string. so if `list` is `['X', 'O']` the result is `"XO"`; see the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) on `str.join`. i added a newline character, so now it should look like the original file

Comment: sorry LAST question! lets say if A1 is X, A2 is O
I want to have a condition when if any ONE of them is false, the writing wrong occur how 
but if all of them are true, the writing will occur, how do it do that? I've been trying for hours

Comment: the simplest way i could think of is to add a flag that you set to true in the beginning. whenever a booking is not possible you set it to false. before writing to the file you check if it's true. see my edit. please update/rephrase your original question so it fits the answer.

Comment: Yea will do, Thanks alot for the help! Really appreciate it